# JAVA What's the requirements of the API for the Comparable interface

Tags: java

I've read the API and also search for the solution but just doesn't help.
 
Please help me with the question
 
Many thanks

Question: Even though the class compiles correctly, it does not satisfy the requirements of the API for the Comparable interface
What is the problem with it? How should it be corrected?

```
public class Name implements Comparable<Name>{
      public String lastName, firstName;
      public Name(String last , String first){
             lastName= last;
             firstName= first;
      }

      public int compareTo(Name other){
           int lastCheck = this.lastName.compareTo(other.lastName);
           if(lastCheck==0){
                return this.firstName.compareTo(other.firstName);
           }else{
                return lastCheck;
           }

      public boolean euqals(Name other){
           return this.lastName.equals(other.lastName);
      }
}
```

Comment: can you post your code here please

Comment: Did you try writing the code in any editor, like IntelliJ or Eclipse? What error do you see?

Comment: This code doesn't compile. Seems it's incorrectedly edited.

Comment: You claim that the code "compiles correctly", it's very clear that it cannot due to `if(lastName==0)` and the weird attempt to embed method `euqals` [sic] inside `compareTo`. Furthermore you completely neglected to mark your attempted overrides with `@Override`, so you missed that `public boolean euqals(Name other)` (if correctly placed) overrides nothing. If you implement `compareTo` it *must* be consistent with the class's override of `equals` and `hashCode`, which you do not override. Fix all that s(tuff) first.

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html),

> **It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required** that `(x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y))`. Generally speaking, any class that implements the Comparable interface and violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. **The recommended language is "Note: this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals**."

In your case, `equals` is not even overriden, pointed by @Lew in the comments. Thus, your code disagrees with the recommendation, and possibly is the answer of the question.

Comment: In fact, `equals` is not even overridden.

Comment: @LewBloch you're right. The name is same, but the signature is different.https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JUKP.jpg. Didn't see at the time of writing. Edited.

Comment: Actually, in the posted code the name was not the same.

Comment: oh, that too. But `equals` receives `Object` as an argument, so either way, the code is incorrect. @LewBloch

Answer (score 1):

The `compareTo` method consideres both last name and first name to calculate whether two `Name` objects are equal, but the `equals` method only checks last name.
This leads to cases where the result of the `compareTo` method indicates that two objects are different, but the `equals` method tells you both are the same.
See [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html):

> It is strongly recommended, but not strictly required that (x.compareTo(y)==0) == (x.equals(y)). Generally speaking, any class that implements the Comparable interface and violates this condition should clearly indicate this fact. The recommended language is "Note: this class has a natural ordering that is inconsistent with equals."

Comment: There is no `equals` override in the posted code. Neither is there a `hashCode` override.

Answer (score 1):

One of the requirements of compareTo is that if `x.compareTo(y) == 0`, then `x.equals(y)` always, and vice versa. In the case of this example, if two names have the same lastName but different firstNames, `a.compareTo(b)` will not return 0, but `a.equals(b)` will.

Comment: so, should I modify it like "return this.lastName.equals(other.lastName)&&this.firstName.equals(other.firstName);" ?

Comment: Yes, two Names are only the same if their lastName and firstName are the same.

Comment: Also, @Timo Thund, you actually have to override `equals` (and `hashCode`).